# Push data into JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JavaScript object -

```
var newArray = { "set1": [], "set2": [] };
```

I am trying to push new data in this like -

```
newArray.set1.push(newSet1);
newArray.set2.push(newSet2);
```

Where `newSet1` and `newSet2` is equal to -

```
[{"test1","test1"},{"test2","test2"}] & [{"test3","test3"},{"test4","test4"}]
```

However when this is getting pushed in it is creating additional square brackets with the end result looking like -

```
{ "set1": [[{"test1","test1"},{"test2","test2"}]], "set2": [[{"test3","test3"},{"test4","test4"}]] }
```

When I actually need -

```
{ "set1": [{"test1","test1"},{"test2","test2"}], "set2": [{"test3","test3"},{"test4","test4"}] }
```

I tried setting my `newArray` as blank like -

```
var newArray = { "set1": '', "set2": '' };
```

However this did not work. How can I adjust it to accept the sets without adding additional brackets?

Comment: newArray.set1 = newArray.set1.concat(<other array>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
var newArray = { "set1": [], "set2": [] };
newArray.set1 = newArray.set1.concat(newSet1);
newArray.set2 = newArray.set2.concat(newSet2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should say

```
newArray.set1.push(newSet1[0]);
newArray.set1.push(newSet1[1]);
newArray.set2.push(newSet2[0]);
newArray.set2.push(newSet2[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`newArray.set1 = newSet1;
newArray.set2 = newSet2;`

Answer (score 0):

Use Like

```
var newArray = { "set1": [], "set2": [] };
var arr1 = new Array ("A", "B", "C");
var arr2 = new Array (1, 2, 3);
var multiArr = new Array (arr1, arr2);
    // or
var multiArr = [arr1, arr2];
    // or
var multiArr = [["A", "B", "C"], [1, 2, 3]];

 // you can access the elements of the array by zero-based indices
var firstRow = multiArr[0]; // same as arr1
var secondRowFirstCell = multiArr[1][0]; // 1
newArray.set1.push(multiArr[0]); //so, you need to use this with
newArray.set1.push(multiArr[1]); //so, you need to use this with
console.log(newArray);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/5cNQr/36/)